# Two identical in class methods with different access modifiers and interface

Tags: c#, .net

I am learning C #.
Below is the code of my program. I don't understand why I can declare two identical methods with different access modifiers, but one with explicit use of the interface in the class that implements the interface. I see with my own eyes that I just can, that's all. But I don't understand the logic. One interface and same method. In a class without an interface implementation, this trick does not work.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }

    interface IMyInterface
    {
        void MyMethod();
    }

    class MyClass : IMyInterface
    {
        public void MyMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(1);
        }

        void IMyInterface.MyMethod() //No error
        {
            Console.WriteLine(1);
        }
    }

    class MyOtherClass
    {
        public void MyOtherMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(1);
        }

        void MyOtherMethod() //Error CS0111
        {
            Console.WriteLine(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation  The interface-specific method is not available on the class and the class-specific method is not available on the interface, so you will see different behavior depending on whether you access the instance as a class instance or an interface instance.

Comment: In one class you are implementing an Interface, which means there is a local version and an interface version of the method.  In the other you are trying to declare same method with different modifiers which is not possible as its in the same class and the compiler would not know the difference.

Comment: To AliK. Thanks. Now it is clear. In MyClass, these are actually different methods, as you said.

Comment: `void IMyInterface.MyMethod()` is an explicit interface implementation. You can think of It as if it does not belong to the class but to the interface - and it's only accessible when your reference type is the interface itself.